# Custom number format function does not work to return 0's as decimals

Tags: javascript, html, rest, coldfusion

My custom number formatting function does not work. It was working fine when the site had a standard client server architecture. However, when we changed to using REST API with javascript and HTML5 the function works for most parts except cases when I need it to display 0's for decimals.

Basically, the function takes arguments the number and the number of decimals and, returns the number rounded to the number of decimals passed. Below, I stripped the function to bare minimum, same as I was testing.

```
<cffunction name="dispCost" access="remote" returntype="string" output="false" hint="Displays costs for a given period to user">
    <cfargument name="in_decCost" type="numeric" required="yes" /> 
    <cfargument name="in_iRound" type="numeric" required="yes" />

    <cfset decRoundedNum = NumberFormat(in_decCost, "_." & RepeatString("9",in_iRound))> 

    <cfreturn decRoundedNum />
</cffunction>
```

When I pass 55.00089 and 3 (dispCost(55.00089,3)), the function returns 55.001.

When I pass 55 or 55.000000 or 55.0000089 and 3 (dispCost(55.0000089,3) or dispCost(55.00000,3)), the function returns 55. And, I need 55.000.

I tried both returntype "string" and "numeric". I tried straight return

```
<cfreturn NumberFormat(in_decCost,"_.000") />
```

Nothing works.

========================================================

UPDATE: 
I called this very function from regular cfm page and it works as expected and returns 55.000. Here is the function call.

> APPLICATION.cfc.calccostcoverage.dispCostPeriod(55,3)

Just wondering if it is something to do with how REST API returning values.

========================================================

I am using CF10 on Windows Server 2008.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Gena

Comment: Where exactly do you get wrong result? Right after calling `dispCost` function or after passing it to js? Your code works fine for me in CF11 environment (returns 55.000), but this `<script>alert(#dispCost(55.00000, 3)#)</script>` shows 55.

Comment: I suppose it isn't CF issue just use [number.toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) js function to display decimals correctly.

Comment: When i do a REST call from URL http://10.200.5.2/rest/select/empselections, right in there i see the value as 55. So, it gets to front end already formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<cfset decRoundedNum = NumberFormat(in_decCost, "_." & RepeatString("9",in_iRound))>
```

to this:

```
<cfset decRoundedNum = NumberFormat(in_decCost, "_." & RepeatString("0",in_iRound))>
```

As per the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=functions_m-r_08.html),  9 is an optional digit while 0 will always appear.

Comment: I tried different masks to straight return "_.000", "_.999"... nothing works. I suspect it has something to do with REST API.